# LTE-HAT GPIO SIM7600

Tags: gpio, internet, hat, modem

I´m able to connect to the internet via the SIM7600 4G HAT modem when it´s connected to USB. Now I´d like to achieve the same without USB but only with the GPIO connection. Somehow the manual (https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/6/6d/SIM7600E-H-4G-HAT-Manual-EN.pdf) is´nt quite explicit on how to achieve this or I´m overlooking something or it´s just not possible.
Some help would be very welcome. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been testing it and I think this needs a certain type of driver or adapter software for the connection to run only by GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi. I only have been successful connecting this SIM7600E-H with the help of Modem Manager, since I cannot establish the IP without it, but been able to register into the NAT by only AT command. Then, with another USB cable connected to the USB entry (not the USB-TO-UART one), Modem Manager can recognize the device by cdc-wdm0 and stablish the connection, being necessary with this setup to registered by AT commands first, then connecting by Modem Manager. The commands I sent to `/dev/serial0`, in my case by minicom, are the next:

```
AT+CENABLELAN=1

AT+CFUN=1,1
```

Then, sometimes the NET led keeps being red, and other times it starts blinking quickly, so the network is registered. Then, with the one USB cable attached (without Modem Manager cannot detect the modem), the modem can be connected by:

```
mmcli -m 0 -e
mmcli -m 0 --simple-connect='apn=,ip-type='

sudo udhcpc -i wwan0
```